# How can I create a custom titlepage like this?

Tags: page, covers, bookcover

I'm trying to create a titlepage like this but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993/37907

Comment: Welcometo TeX.SE! Please show us, what you try so far!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you like it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=25mm,
}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor}
\definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\pagecolor{azure}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\draw [white,line width=10mm]
(current page.south west)
rectangle
(current page.north east)
}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace{10cm}
\color{white}

{\Huge\textbf{Example}}\vspace{6mm}

{\LARGE\textit{Independent degree project - first cycle}}

\vfill

\large\textbf{Main subject}\\
\textit{Major subject}\vspace{6mm}

\textbf{Title}\\
Header\vspace{6mm}

\textbf{Name}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you! Looks great!

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to upvote the answer if it has the result that you desired. Have a nice day `@Karl`!